# How to display separate results for each thread group in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a question about the results sampler.
I have a test plan with two thread groups, that I want to run together.
The problem is that I see in the results combination off the two thread groups.

I want that in the results listener of the first thread group only it's results will be displayed.
and in the results of the second tread group only it's results will be displayed.

I put results listener under the debug sampler but it is not display anything. only the result listener in the test plan level, and it display combined data.
can someone please advise?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is [not to use any JMeter Listeners](http://Greedy%20Listeners%20-%20Memory%20Leeches%20of%20Performance%20Testing) as they don't add any value and create unnecessary memory and especially disk IO overhead.

Instead of it I would suggest

1. Giving your Thread Groups different names like `Thread Group 1`, `Thread Group 2,` etc.
2. Running your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   Once done you will see `threadName` column in the .jtl results file, you can sort this on Thread Group name according to your requirements

   [image: JMeter Thread Group Name]

---

Alternative option is using [Filter Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/), it allows filtering the .jtl results file and including only those sample results which match the specified pattern

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, I am not running the same thread group in loop, I have two different thread groups (I duplicate them) I want to run them together , but to see in each thread group each results, Filter results tool is for if I have one thread group and creat loop of threads (user). I want to run two thread groups together.  today for runing tests I need to run one by one, and disable the previouse thread group. I their a way to run multiple thread groups and check results ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the listeners in each Thread Group. that way you are defining the scope of the listener to specific to the thread group.

Refer the following to know scoping rules:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules